# ASP.NET MVC 5 - return special error page instead of custom error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I am not entirely sure about the title of my question. What I need is to set up custom error pages for common errors - 404, 500, etc. but I also need my own "special" error pages for particular errors.

I configured custom error pages served by IIS like below and it is working fine. Something happens, error 500 is raised and `/Error/InternalServerError` is served and original URL is kept.

But if I access `/Error/Special` I have problem. If I set status code to 500, I will get content of error page `/Error/InternalServerError` instead of content 
 of `/Error/Special` with status code 500. `TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` is not working because of `web.config`.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/InternalServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And this controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // special error page
    public ActionResult Special()
    {
        //Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // <- I cant set status code because IIS returns error page (custom error page) instead
        //Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; // <- needs httpErrors - existingResponse="Passthrough" but custom error pages are not working with it
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult InternalServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Why I need "special" error pages? I want to do something like this:

```
public class SpecialController : Controller
{      
    public SpecialController()
    {
        // something
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if ( something != true )
        {
            // it would be nice to do it without redirect, just return /Error/Special and stop executing original request
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            { "action", "Special" },
                            { "controller", "Error" }
                        });
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog could helps you. It did it for me years ago.

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Comment: Please, be more specific.As you can see, I got custom error pages working. But I have different problem, I need to disable custom error pages for specific action and use that action later.

Comment: maybe you can produce a custom error code and redirect that code to specific controller? for example 999 then redirect to your controller

Comment: I dont think that "inventing" HTTP status code is a correct way even that it could work - web browser would get unknown status code.

Comment: Yes you can do it if you respect the RFC                                                    
1xx: Informational - Request received, continuing process

2xx: Success - The action was successfully received, understood, and accepted

3xx: Redirection - Further action must be taken in order to complete the request

4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled

5xx: Server Error - The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request [1]:

Comment: [RFC 2616][1]:
"HTTP status codes are extensible. HTTP applications are not required to understand the meaning of all registered status codes, though such understanding is obviously desirable. However, applications MUST understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first digit, and treat any unrecognized response as being equivalent to the x00 status code of that class